# What is the difference between spare time and leisure time and free time?

Tags: word-choice

For example, 
After the kid goes to the school, she has more "free time" or "leisure time" or "spare time".
Are these words all correct in this sentence? If so, what is difference and which one is most common in colloquial English?

Comment: Does "she" refer to the child's mother?

Answer (score 10):

They're all correct. "Spare time" and "free time" are the most common, but "leisure time" is more specific -- it means that you're not working. Free time and spare time usually is taken to mean "time that I'm not on-duty for my regular job," or "time when I'm not at school" for a youngster. So it would be normal to say "I need to use some of my free time to cut the grass," but usually when someone refers to "leisure time" they're doing something they enjoy during that time, not chores.

Comment: Worth noting that "spare time" and "free time" are also used in a work context for "time when your primary role is not occupying you and you are able to work on secondary tasks" -- not at all "leisure time"